# Regular expression which allow only characters or space

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I need help with regular expression.I need a expression in jquery which allows only character or space between two words. no double space allowed

I am using this

```
/^[a-zA-Z]+(-_ [a-zA-Z]+)*/
```

but it's not working.

**Example**
 space hello - not allowed

hello space - not allowed

hello space  space hello - not allowed

space hello space  - not allowed

hello1234 - not allowed

hello space 1234 - not allowed

---

hello world-allowed

hello-allowed

hello how are you-allowed

Comment: Will there be any punctuation (e.g. `,` `.` `?`)? A full sentence or only two words?

Comment: no only words that can be more than two.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

you can use this

```
/^([a-zA-Z]+\s)*[a-zA-Z]+$/
```

Answer (score 0):

I see you already have an accepted answer, but here's another, more concise option:

```
/^\w+( \w+)*$/
```

Starts with a word, then followed by any number of words with a single space in front.

Note that this accepts numbers in words too. I don't know if that's what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Well this RegEx worked for me ([A-Za-z]*( )*[A-Za-z]+)